# Why two similar, but different series converges to one result $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, pi, infinite-product

We can be sure, that
$$\prod\limits_{p}^{\infty}\frac{p}{p-1}\prod\limits_{p[4k+1]}^{\infty}\frac{p-1}{p+1}=\pi$$
and
$$\prod\limits_{p}^{\infty}\frac{p}{p-1}\prod\limits_{p[6k+1]}^{\infty}\frac{p-1}{p+1}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$$
so
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=\prod\limits_{p[4k+1]}^{\infty}\frac{p+1}{p-1}\prod\limits_{p[6k+1]}^{\infty}\frac{p-1}{p+1}=\left(\frac{5+1}{5-1}\right)\left(\frac{7-1}{7+1}\right)\left(\frac{17+1}{17-1}\right)\left(\frac{19-1}{19+1}\right)\cdots$$
For all $p[12k+1]$ that production is equal to $1$, so
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{9}{8}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{15}{14}\cdot\frac{15}{16}\cdots$$
It might seem, that this result is equal to
$$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(6n-3)^2}{(6n-2)(6n-4)}\right]=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$
but it actually is. This two series are similar, but different. There are some terms in second infinite production, which are absent in first:
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{9}{8}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{15}{14}\cdot\frac{15}{16}\cdot \frac{21}{20}\cdot\frac{21}{22}\cdot\frac{27}{26}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{27}{28}}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{33}{32}}\cdot\frac{33}{34}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{39}{38}}\cdot\frac{39}{40}\cdot\frac{45}{44}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{45}{46}}\cdot\frac{51}{50}\cdot\frac{51}{52}\cdots$$
Part of them smaller than $1$, other part - bigger. Also there is no terms in first production, which are absent in second. So if we extract this (colored red) terms, their infinite production equal to $1$. Another words, we can say, that
$$\prod\limits_{s[12k+5]}^{\infty}\frac{s+1}{s-1}\prod\limits_{s[12k+7]}^{\infty}\frac{s-1}{s+1}=1$$

Here $s[mk+n]$ - composite number of form $mk+n$. But why?

Why are they equal to one result?

If I made some mistakes, sorry for my English.

Comment: You wrote, "It might seem that this result is equal to [...], but it actually is." Do you mean it actually is *not*?

Comment: @Théophile, thank you for comment! Sorry for my English. I mean if someone will start to calculate production by primes and see pattern before getting few terms, to see terms, colored red, he can make wrong assumption, that all terms in first and second production absolutely identical, but, as I wrote next, there are not. Can you help me right it more simply and correctly in English?

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in your *so* part:

According to you, if $a_p$ and $b_p$ are two series: $$\prod a_p \, \prod b_p = \zeta \implies \prod a_p = \zeta \prod \frac1{b_p}$$

How is this true? For example, take $b_p= p^2$. Does the result follow?

Comment: Thank you for comment! I agree with you - infinite production will be equal to $0$. But $$\prod\limits_{p[4k+1]}^{\infty}\frac{p+1}{p-1}\prod\limits_{p[6k+1]}^{\infty}\frac{p-1}{p+1} is actually equal to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}.

Comment: @user514787 I don’t think you understand my point. I have no objection in your final result. But, notice the third step starting with “so”. How do you justify your taking reciprocal of the second product to bring it to the RHS?

Comment: I have some problems with English, math and finally with thinking, sorry. Defect step was deleted. Now we have result after "so" by simply division.

Comment: @user514787 Yes, you are right now.